# Compare two files to find common, and unique entries

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I would like to compare entries in two files.

#### first file

```
ch1 12345 ch1 12900 Del
ch1 13000 ch1 13689 Del
ch2 14567 ch2 14905 Del
ch4 23001 ch4 26019 Del
```

#### second file

```
ch1 12309 ch1 12865 
ch2 14531 ch2 14871 
ch3 16909 ch3 16990
ch4 45401 ch4 45810
```

- Entries common to both the first and second file (criteria for common entries have at least 50 position on both sides)

  ```
  ch1 12345 ch1 12900 Del, ch1 12309 ch1 12865
  ch2 14567 ch2 14905 Del, ch2 14531 ch2 14871
  ```
- Entries unique to the first file

  ```
  ch1 13000 ch1 13689 Del
  ch4 23001 ch4 26019 Del
  ```
- Entries unique to the second file

  ```
  ch3 16909 ch3 1699
  ch4 45401 ch4 45810
  ```

I have written a Perl program looping one array within another array and identified the common entries, but with this approach I can't identify the unique entries.

Comment: Please show the code you already have.

Comment: I assume that every second line of your data isn't really blank? Stack Overflow uses *Markdown* and you should read and understand [*Markdown help*](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) before posting again

Comment: What does *"criteria for common entries have at least 50 position on both sides"* mean? I don't understand what it means to have 50 positions both sides of a criterion.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following program.

If you change your mind about how many occurences must be
on both sides, change the value of `$limit` variable.
Maybe just 1 would be enough?

```
use strict; use warnings;
# Count text occurrences in 2 files

my %counts;         # Hash of arrays (occurrence counters)

sub inputProcess {
  # Process input file
  my $fn = shift;   # File name
  my $n = shift;    # Counter index
  open (my $fh, '<', $fn) or die "Can't open $fn: $!";
  while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    $counts{$_}[$n]++;
  }
}

sub readCounts {
  # Read counters, substituting 0 if any does not exist
  my $cnt = shift;  # Reference to array of counters
  my @v = (0, 0);
  foreach my $i ( 0 .. $#v ) {
    $v[$i] = $cnt->[$i] if exists $cnt->[$i];
  }
  return @v;
}

sub printUniq {
  # Print unique entries for the given counter
  my $myCnt = shift;            # "My" counter
  my $otherCnt = 1 - $myCnt;    # The "other" counter
  print "Unique entries from file $myCnt:\n";
  foreach my $key (sort keys %counts) {
    my $val = $counts{$key};
    my @v = readCounts($val);
    if ($v[$myCnt] > 0 && $v[$otherCnt] == 0) {
      printf "%s\n", $key;
    }
  }
}

sub printCommon {
  # Print common entries for both files
  print "Common entries for both files:\n";
  my $limit = 50;
  foreach my $key (sort keys %counts) {
    my $val = $counts{$key};
    my @v = readCounts($val);
    if ($v[0] >= $limit && $v[1] >= $limit) {
      printf "%s\n", $key;
    }
  }
}

inputProcess('Inp1.txt', 0);
inputProcess('Inp2.txt', 1);
print "All entries and counts\n";
foreach my $key (sort keys %counts) {
  my $val = $counts{$key};
  my ($v0, $v1) = readCounts($val);
  printf "%-16s / %3d, %3d\n", $key, $v0, $v1;
}
printUniq(0);
printUniq(1);
printCommon();
```

The idea is to use hash of (references to) arrays.
The key is just the entry read from a file.
Each array (value in the hash) contains 2 counters, for both files.

The program prints sorted entries, but if you wish, just remove
the sorting.

Writing the above program, I assumed that **each whole line** is a separate entry. If it is not the case, modyfiy *inputProcess* function accordingly.

And one more remark: The first file contains *Del* at the end of each line,
whereas the second file doesn't. Such entries (full lines) will not "match".